# How to not confuse the mouse click and mouse down event in windows forms?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a MenuStrip from which I want to drag some things on the form body(then some things happen such as the backcolor of the form is changing, etc). I am handling the MouseDown event, but the thing is that when I click on the option in the `ToolStripMenu` the same things happen(the backcolor of the form is changing, etc).
What I want is to somehow separate the `MouseClick` from the `MouseDown`. More precisely, when I click on one option of the `MenuStrip` I don't want anything to happen.

When I click, the `MouseDown` event fires. I want to ignore it unless the mouse's cursor moves.

```
private void salmonToolStripMenuItem_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    //gets the cursor position at the moment when mouse down is activated
    p1M = Cursor.Position.X;
    p2M = Cursor.Position.Y;
    //miscare shows if the mouse moved
    if (miscare == true)
    {
        //do things 
    }
}

private void Rezervare1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
}

private void salmonToolStripMenuItem_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{    
    //gets the cursor position to see if it moved
    p1m = Cursor.Position.X;
    p2m = Cursor.Position.Y;
    if (p1M != p1m || p2M != p2m)
    {
        miscare = true;//it means the cursor moved
    }
    else miscare = false;
}
```

Comment: You have to show us your code.

Comment: done it, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your logic to happen on mouse move, then lets handle `MouseMove`!

```
bool isMouseDown = false;

private void salmonToolStripMenuItem_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{ 
    isMouseDown = true;
}

private void salmonToolStripMenuItem_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{ 
    isMouseDown = false;
}

private void salmonToolStripMenuItem_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if(isMouseDown)
    {
        //Do your thing
    }
}
```

Also note, there are some strange edge cases you can hit with things like the form losing focus, or the user dragging outside of the bounds of the form.  Something to be aware of and handle as needed.